# Smart banner on iOS 6 simulator not working

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

The Smart app banner seems to work on device but it doesn't seem to trigger on the simulator device.

I am currently running iOS6 on an iphone 4 inch retina simulator.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html):

> Banners won’t appear in the iOS Simulator.

Answer (score 4):

It isn't possible to launch the AppStore on the iPhone Simulator. Then, when you try to open the link, simulator doesn't react to this action.

I've tested this feature with the app installed on the simulator and this doesn't work, so I think Apple has not implemented it on the simulator.

Comment: the issue I'm having is that I'm not even seeing the banner or link, let alone testing the actual link itself.

Comment: Try accessing other webs from simulator that implement Smart App Banners, like https://www.ulabox.com/ or http://m.offerum.com/. Both use <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=ITUNES_APP_ID"> to show the banner.